# Is OAuth Consent Screen verification required to even test the Smart Device API

Tags: nest-device-access

When adding the sdm.service scope to the Oauth consent screen, it triggers a warning that verification is required. I'm wondering if verification is required even if I am just creating a test app that won't be published?

Through my many many weeks of trying, I've only been able to actually link my test app to an account twice, and I still don't know why it only worked those two times. I usually end up on the No Partner Connection Found screen after the Google Nest Permissions screen. There is no redirect and so no authorization code to actually access anything. I've tried with clean, brand new projects, with different email accounts, and even through different means of access. At this point, the only thing left that I can think of is that maybe my Oauth consent screen needs to be verified. But, the verification process requires information that I just do not have.

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to link your personal account through the API for personal use without going through OAuth Verification. What type of Client ID are you attempting to create?

Have you tried to get through the entire flow using the process described in the Quick Start guide?  https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/get-started

Comment: Yeah, I've been using the get started guide as a reference all this time. I think I finally got it working consistently now, but only through a web application. Still can't get it working in an android application. I don't think I've done anything different from before. My suspicions is that it has something to do with the redirect URI. Seems that one of the two potential issues that can come out of an improper or incorrect redirect URI is either an out right error or what I've been seeing, which can be confusing.

Comment: Sorry for the late follow up, but you do not have to go through OAuth verification for personal use: (https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#zippy=%2Cexceptions-to-verification-requirements).  Not having the scope in the OAuth consent screen shouldn't block you from using the API with a personal account/app.  You should just get an "unverified" warning but you can continue past this.